# in a dictionary with values being single integer change them into a list

Tags: python, dictionary

for simplicity my dictionary looks like:

```
data ={"a": 12, "b": 13, "c": 22, "d": 33}
```

I have huge dictionary. What would be the most efficient way to convert all values in key-value pair into a list containing single integer

I've tried

```
for key in data:
    data[key] = list(data[key])
```

giving me:

> TypeError:'int' object not iterable.

does it mean I cannot convert single integer into a list?

I can get desired output by:

```
for key in data:
    lst = []
    lst.append(data[key])
    data[key] = lst
```

but feels like there is a more efficient way.

**desired output**:

```
  data ={"a": [12], "b": [13], "c": [22], "d": [33]}
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: You can try using dictionary comprehension, {k:[v] for k, v in data.items()}

Comment: @sid I've clearly stated desired output before. Which part is unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dict-comprehension as follows:

```py
data = {key: [value] for key, value in data.items()}
```

Running example:

```
>>> data ={"a":12, "b":13, "c":22, "d":33}
>>> data = {key: [value] for key, value in data.items()}
>>> data
{'a': [12], 'b': [13], 'c': [22], 'd': [33]}
```

I also used `ipython` to see what solution is more effective if mine or @Selcuk, and these are the results:

```
In [1]:
%%timeit
data ={"a":12, "b":13, "c":22, "d":33}
data = {key: [value] for key, value in data.items()}
1.05 µs ± 18.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

```
In[2]:
%%timeit
data ={"a":12, "b":13, "c":22, "d":33}
data.update((k, [v]) for k, v in data.items())
1.61 µs ± 34.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: The OP's code replaces the values of the keys of the original dict in-place, while this answer creates a new dict, which may not be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
data.update((k, [v]) for k, v in data.items())
```

This will result in:

```
{'a': [12], 'c': [22], 'b': [13], 'd': [33]}
```